# All 108 Names of Maa Durga?

Tags: festivals, durga, goddess, navrathri

According Hindu Mythology Maa Durga has lots of avtars with various powers. Navratri vrat is dedicated to Maa Durga's nine forms. What is about other forms of Maa Durga ??  Names of Maa Durga and their meanings with significance of worshiping them ???

Comment: [दुर्गाष्टोत्तरशतनामावली](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durgaa108-5.html?lang=sa) ([Durga Ashtottarashatanamavali 108 names](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durgaa108-5.itx))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

|| durgaa ashTottara shata [naamaavalee](http://www.bharatiweb.com/new/wp-content/uploads/Durga-Ashtottara-Shata-Namavali-Eng-v1.pdf) ||

> om shriyai nama: 
>   om umaayai nama: 
>   om bhaaratyai nama: 
>   om bhadraayai nama: 
>   om sharvaaNyai nama: 
>   om vijayaayai nama: 
>   om jayaayai nama: 
>   om vaaNyai nama: 
>   om sarvagataayai nama: 
>   om gauryai nama: |10|
>
> om vaaraahyai nama: 
>   om kamalapriyaayai nama: 
>   om sarasvatyai nama: 
>   om kamalaayai nama: 
>   om maayaayai nama: 
>   om maatangyai nama: 
>   om aparaayai nama: 
>   om ajaayai nama: 
>   om shaankabharyai nama: 
>   om shivaayai nama: |20|
>
> om chaNDayai nama: 
>   om kuNDalyai nama: 
>   om vaishNavyai nama: 
>   om kriyaayai nama: 
>   om shriyai nama: 
>   om aindrayai nama: 
>   om madhumatyai nama: 
>   om girijaayai nama: 
>   om subhagaayai nama: 
>   om ambikaayai nama: |30|
>
> om taaraayai nama: 
>   om padmaavatyai nama: 
>   om hansaayai nama: 
>   om padmanaabhasahodaryai nama: 
>   om aparNaayai nama: 
>   om lalitaayai nama: 
>   om dhaatryai nama: 
>   om kumaaryai nama: 
>   om shikhavaahinyai nama: 
>   om shaambhavyai nama: |40|
>
> om sumukhyai nama: 
>   om maitryai nama: 
>   om trinetraayai nama: 
>   om vishvaroopiNyai nama: 
>   om aaryaayai nama: 
>   om mruDaanyai nama: 
>   om heemkaaryai nama: 
>   om krodhinyai nama: 
>   om sudinaayai nama: 
>   om achalaayai nama: |50|
>
> om sookshmaayai nama: 
>   om paraatparaayai nama: 
>   om shobhaayai nama: 
>   om sarvavarNaayai nama: 
>   om harapriyaayai nama: 
>   om mahaalakshmyai nama: 
>   om mahaasiddhayai nama: 
>   om svadhaayai nama: 
>   om svaahaayai nama: 
>   om manonmanyai nama: |60|
>
> om trilokapaalinyai nama: 
>   om udhbhootaayai nama: 
>   om trisandhyaayai nama: 
>   om tripuraantakyai nama: 
>   om trishaktyai nama: 
>   om tripadaayai nama: 
>   om durgaayai nama: 
>   om braahmayai nama: 
>   om trailokyavaasinyai nama: 
>   om pushkaraayai nama: |70|
>
> om atrisutaayai nama: 
>   om gooDhaayai nama: 
>   om trivarNaayai nama: 
>   om trisvaraayai nama: 
>   om triguNaayai nama:
>
> om nirguNaayai nama: 
>   om satyaayai nama: 
>   om nirvikalpaayai nama: 
>   om niranjinyai nama: 
>   om jvaalinyai nama: |80|
>
> om maalinyai nama: 
>   om charchaayai nama: 
>   om kravyaadopa nibarhiNyai nama: 
>   om kaamaakshyai nama: 
>   om kaaminyai nama: 
>   om kaantaayai nama: 
>   om kaamadaayai nama: 
>   om kalahansinyai nama: 
>   om salajjaayai nama: 
>   om kulajaayai nama: |90|
>
> om praagnyai nama: 
>   om prabhaayai nama: 
>   om madanasundaryai nama: 
>   om vaageeshvaryai nama: 
>   om vishaalaakshyai nama: 
>   om sumangalyai nama: 
>   om kaalyai nama: 
>   om maheshvaryai nama: 
>   om chaNDyai nama: 
>   om bhairavyai nama: |100|
>
> om bhuvaneshvaryai nama: 
>   om nityaayai nama: 
>   om saanandavibhavaayai nama: 
>   om satyagyaanaayai nama: 
>   om tamopahaayai nama: 
>   om maheshvarapriyankaryai nama: 
>   om mahaatripurasundaryai nama: 
>   om durgaaparameshvaryai nama: 
>   |108|

Apart from this there are 9 major forms of durga,

```
Śailaputrī शैलपुत्री

Brahmachāriṇī व्रह्मचारणी

Candraghaṇṭā चन्द्रघण्टा

Kuśamāṇḍā कुशमाण्डा

Skandamātā स्कन्दमाता

Kātyāyanī कात्यायनी

Kālarātrī कालरात्री

Mahāgaurī महागौरी

Siddhidātrī सिद्धिदात्री
```

Meanings of the 108 names of Goddess Durga from [this](http://www.drikpanchang.com/hindu-names/goddesses/durga/108-durga-names.html) page are as follows:

> 1. श्री    ॐ श्रियै नमः।   Shree   Auspicious
> 2. उमा     ॐ उमायै नमः।    Uma     Mother or Lady of the Mountains
> 3. भारती   ॐ भारत्यै नमः।      Bharati     Goddess of Speech
> 4. भद्रा   ॐ भद्रायै नमः।      Bhadra
> 5. शर्वाणी     ॐ शर्वाण्यै नमः।    Sharvani    Consort of Sharva
> 6. विजया   ॐ विजयायै नमः।      Vijaya      Conqueror
> 7. जया     ॐ जयायै नमः।    Jaya    The Victorious
> 8. वाणी    ॐ वाण्यै नमः।   Vani
> 9. सर्वगताय    ॐ सर्वगतायै नमः।    Sarvagataya
> 10. गौरी    ॐ गौर्यै नमः।   Gauri   Goddess of Purity and Posterity
> 11. वाराही      ॐ वाराह्यै नमः।     Varahi      Shakti of Varaha, A Sow Headed Goddess
> 12. कमलप्रिया   ॐ कमलप्रियायै नमः।      Kamalapriya
> 13. सरस्वती     ॐ सरस्वत्यै नमः।    Saraswati   The Goddess of Learning
> 14. कमला    ॐ कमलायै नमः।   Kamala
> 15. माया    ॐ मायायै नमः।   Maya    She Who is Illusion
> 16. मातंगी      ॐ मातंग्यै नमः।     Maatangi    Goddess of Matanga
> 17. अपरा    ॐ अपरायै नमः।   Apra
> 18. अजा     ॐ अजायै नमः।    Aja     She Who Has No Birth
> 19. शांकभर्यै   ॐ शांकभर्यै नमः।    Shankbharye
> 20. शिवा    ॐ शिवायै नमः।   Shiva   Shiva's Half
> 21. चण्डी   ॐ चण्डयै नमः।   Chandi      The Fierce Goddess
> 22. कुण्डलिनी   ॐ कुण्डल्यै नमः।    Kundalini   She Who Has the Form a Coil
> 23. वैष्णवी     ॐ वैष्णव्यै नमः।    Vaishnavi   The Invincible
> 24. क्रियायै    ॐ क्रियायै नमः।     Kriyayai
> 25. श्री    ॐ श्रियै नमः।   Shri    Auspicious
> 26. इन्दिरा     ॐ ऐन्द्रयै नमः।     Indira      The Goddess Lakshmi, Wife of the God Vishnu
> 27. मधुमती      ॐ मधुमत्यै नमः।     Madhumati   She Whose Nature is as Sweet as Honey
> 28. गिरिजा      ॐ गिरिजायै नमः।     Girija      Daughter of Himalaya
> 29. सुभगा   ॐ सुभगायै नमः।      Subhaga     She Who is the Seat of all Prosperity
> 30. अंबिका      ॐ अंबिकायै नमः।     Ambika      The Mother of the Universe
> 31. तारा    ॐ तारायै नमः।   Tara    One Who Ferries Across (Samsara)
> 32. पद्मावती    ॐ पद्मावत्यै नमः।   Padmavati   Possessing Lotus
> 33. हंसा    ॐ हंसायै नमः।   Hansa
> 34. पद्मनाभसहोदरी   ॐ पद्मनाभसहोदर्यै नमः।      Padmanabha sahodari     She Who is Vishhnu's Sister
> 35. अपर्णा      ॐ अपर्णायै नमः।     Aparna      She Who Doesn't Eat Even Leaves While Fasting
> 36. ललितायै     ॐ ललितायै नमः।      Lalita      She Who is Pleasant, Charming, Desirable
> 37. धात्री      ॐ धात्र्यै नमः।     Dhatri
> 38. कुमारी      ॐ कुमार्यै नमः।     Kumari      The Beautiful Adolescent
> 39. शिखवाहिन्यै     ॐ शिखवाहिन्यै नमः।      Shikhvahinyai
> 40. शांभवी      ॐ शांभव्यै नमः।     Shambhavi   The Consort of Shambhava
> 41. सुमुखी      ॐ सुमुख्यै नमः।     Sumukhi     She Who Has A Beautiful Face
> 42. मैत्र्यै    ॐ मैत्र्यै नमः।     Maitryai
> 43. त्रिनेत्रा      ॐ त्रिनेत्रायै नमः।     Trinetra    One Who Has Three-Eyes
> 44. विश्वरूपा   ॐ विश्वरूपिण्यै नमः।    Vishvarupa      She Who Has The Whole Universe As Her Form
> 45. आर्य    ॐ आर्यायै नमः।      Aarya   Goddess
> 46. मृडानी      ॐ मृडान्यै नमः।     Mridani     She Who Gives Pleasure
> 47. हींकार्यै   ॐ हींकार्यै नमः।    Hinkaryai
> 48. क्रोधिन्यै      ॐ क्रोधिन्यै नमः।   Krodhinyai
> 49. सुदिनायै    ॐ सुदिनायै नमः।     Sudinayai
> 50. अचल     ॐ अचलायै नमः।   Achala      The Immovable One
> 51. सूक्ष्म     ॐ सूक्ष्मायै नमः।   Sukshma     Subtle
> 52. परात्परायै      ॐ परात्परायै नमः।   Paratpara   She Who Is The Most Supreme Of The Supreme Ones
> 53. शोभा    ॐ शोभायै नमः।   Shobha      Brilliance
> 54. सर्ववर्णायै     ॐ सर्ववर्णायै नमः।      Sarvavarna      All Coloured
> 55. हरप्रिया    ॐ हरप्रियायै नमः।   Haripriya
> 56. महालक्ष्मी      ॐ महालक्ष्म्यै नमः।     Mahalakshmi     She Who Is The Great Goddess Lakshmi
> 57. महासिद्धि   ॐ महासिद्धयै नमः।   Mahasiddhi
> 58. स्वधा   ॐ स्वधायै नमः।      Swadha      Shape of Swadhadevi
> 59. स्वाहा      ॐ स्वाहायै नमः।     Swaha   Shape of Swahadevi (Auspicious)
> 60. मनोन्मनी    ॐ मनोन्मन्यै नमः।   Manonmani   She Who is Shiva's Shakti
> 61. त्रिलोकपालिनी   ॐ त्रिलोकपालिन्यै नमः।      Trilokapalini
> 62. उद्भूतायै   ॐ उद्भूतायै नमः।    Udbhutayai
> 63. त्रिसन्ध्या     ॐ त्रिसन्ध्यायै नमः।    Trisandhya      Name of Goddess Durga
> 64. त्रिपुरान्तक्यै     ॐ त्रिपुरान्तक्यै नमः।      Tripurantakyai
> 65. त्रिशक्त्यै     ॐ त्रिशक्त्यै नमः।      Trishaktyai
> 66. त्रिपदायै   ॐ त्रिपदायै नमः।    Tripadayai
> 67. दुर्गा      ॐ दुर्गायै नमः।     Durga   Remover of Distress
> 68. ब्राह्मी    ॐ ब्राह्मयै नमः।    Brahmi      Power of God Brahma
> 69. त्रैलोक्यवासिनी     ॐ त्रैलोक्यवासिन्यै नमः।    Trailokyavasini
> 70. पुष्करा     ॐ पुष्करायै नमः।    Pushkara    She Who Is Complete
> 71. अत्रिसुतायै     ॐ अत्रिसुतायै नमः।      Atrisutayai
> 72. गूढ़ा    ॐ गूढ़ायै नमः।   Gudha
> 73. त्रिवर्णा   ॐ त्रिवर्णायै नमः।      Trivarna
> 74. त्रिस्वरा   ॐ त्रिस्वरायै नमः।      Triswara
> 75. त्रिगुणा    ॐ त्रिगुणायै नमः।   Triguna     She Who Is Endowed With The Three Gunas Of Sattva, Rajas And Tamas
> 76. निर्गुणा    ॐ निर्गुणायै नमः।   Nirguna     She Who Is Beyond All Three Gunas Of Nature, Namely Sattva, Rajas And Tamas
> 77. सत्या   ॐ सत्यायै नमः।      Satya   The Truth
> 78. निर्विकल्पा     ॐ निर्विकल्पायै नमः।    Nirvikalpa      She Who Is Free Of False Imaginings
> 79. निरन्जना    ॐ निरंजिन्यै नमः।   Niranjana   She Who Stays Unattached, Bound To Nothing
> 80. ज्वालिन्यै      ॐ ज्वालिन्यै नमः।   Jwalinyai
> 81. मालिनी      ॐ मालिन्यै नमः।     Malini      She Who Is Wearing Garlands
> 82. चर्चायै     ॐ चर्चायै नमः।      Charchayai
> 83. क्रव्यादोप निबर्हिण्यै      ॐ क्रव्यादोप निबर्हिण्यै नमः।   Kravyadopa nibarhinyai
> 84. कामाक्षी    ॐ कामाक्ष्यै नमः।   Kamakshi    She Whose Eyes Awaken Desire
> 85. कामिन्यै    ॐ कामिन्यै नमः।     Kaminyai
> 86. कान्ता      ॐ कान्तायै नमः।     Kanta   She Who Is Beautiful
> 87. कामदायै     ॐ कामदायै नमः।      Kamdaayai
> 88. कलहंसिन्यै      ॐ कलहंसिन्यै नमः।   Kalahansinyai
> 89. सलज्जायै    ॐ सलज्जायै नमः।     Salajjaayai
> 90. कुलजायै     ॐ कुलजायै नमः।      Kulajaayai
> 91. प्राज्ञ्यै      ॐ प्राज्ञ्यै नमः।   Pragyai
> 92. प्रभा   ॐ प्रभायै नमः।      Prabha
> 93. मदनसुन्दरी      ॐ मदनसुन्दर्यै नमः।     Madanasundari
> 94. वागीश्वरी   ॐ वागीश्वर्यै नमः।      Vagishvari      The Sovereign Goddess of Speech
> 95. विशालाक्षी      ॐ विशालाक्ष्यै नमः।     Vishalakshi     She Who Has Large Eyes
> 96. सुमङ्गली    ॐ सुमंगल्यै नमः।    Sumangali   She Who Is Eternally Auspicious
> 97. काली    ॐ काल्यै नमः।   Kali    Dark-Complexioned Goddess
> 98. महेश्वरी    ॐ महेश्वर्यै नमः।   Maheshvari      She Who Is The Wife Of Maheshvara
> 99. चण्डी   ॐ चण्ड्यै नमः।      Chandi      Great Goddess, Angry name of Goddess Shakti
> 100. भैरवी   ॐ भैरव्यै नमः।      Bhairavi    She Who Is The Wife Of Bhairava (Shiva)
> 101. भुवनेश्वरी      ॐ भुवनेश्वर्यै नमः।     Bhuvaneshvari   She Who Is The Ruler Of The Universe
> 102. नित्या      ॐ नित्यायै नमः।     Nitya   She Who Is Eternal
> 103. सानन्दविभवायै   ॐ सानन्दविभवायै नमः।    Sanandavibhvayai
> 104. सत्यज्ञाना      ॐ सत्यज्ञानायै नमः।     Satyagyana      She Who Is Truth, Knowledge And Bliss
> 105. तमोपहा      ॐ तमोपहायै नमः।     Tamopaha    She Who Removes The Ignorance Born Of Tamas
> 106. महेश्वरप्रियंकर्यै      ॐ महेश्वरप्रियंकर्यै नमः।   Maheshvarpriyankaryai
> 107. महात्रिपुरसुन्दरी   ॐ महात्रिपुरसुन्दर्यै नमः।      Maha Tripura Sundari    She Who Is The Great Tripurasundari
> 108. दुर्गापरमेश्वर्यै   ॐ दुर्गापरमेश्वर्यै नमः।    Durgaparmeshvaryai